# How can I call external JS from another JS by Protractor JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I'm using Jasmine as my JS framework to my automated test scripts.

I want to call another JS file from another test script.

Something like:

```
describe('call JS Testing', function() {

var exScripts = function(script){
exScripts.src = 'c:\\automation\\tests\\';
};


  it('call to script', function() {
      exScripts('onboarding.js');
    });
});
```

Is it possible to do it without depending Jquery / Ajax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be done using `require()` function .

for example

```
require('C:/automation/tests/onboarding.js');
```